# Can ServletFileUpload.parseRequest() only be called once per request?

Tags: grails, file-upload, apache-commons

I'm working a custom SpringSecurityFilter for my Grails application and I'm trying to use the commons upload library to process the request. I'm able to process the request in the filter but once it gets to my controller, none of the values are available.

Can the HttpRequest only be processed once by the upload library? I'm guessing it's cleaning up the temp files. Is there a way to keep them around so they can be processed again at the controller level?

I need to interrogate a form parameter for the security (due to the client I can't add it to the http headers) but once I get the value, it seems to wipe the request for further processing.

Comment: hi tgm, i have the same question as yours. Did you find the solution out?

Comment: Not yet. I tried writing custom security filters but to no success. We added headers for normal authentication and went with session authentication to get around the problem for now. When I get the time, I plan to try using Shiro instead or build custom grails authentication filters (which work). Try the Grails Filters route if you're not tied to SpringSecurity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. A Request can only be parsed once.

I saw this answer on Apache's FAQ page for FileUpload.

**Question: Why is parseRequest() returning no items?**

*Answer: "This most commonly happens when the request has already been parsed, or processed in some other way. Since the input stream has aleady been consumed by that earlier process, it is no longer available for parsing by Commons FileUpload."*

Reference: http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/faq.html